# accessing class_attribute from module in Rails 4

Tags: module, ruby-on-rails-4, attr-accessible

I have a module that defines custom `attr_accessible` attribute as follow:

```
module MyModule
    include ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity
    %w[var1 var2].each do |key|
        attr_accessible key
    end
end

class MyClass
    include MyModule
end
```

Since attr_accessible is defined in `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity`, I include it in `MyModule`.
However, when I call `object = MyClass.first; object.var1`

I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `class_attribute'
```

Now, this method seems to be defined in active_support/core_ext/class.rb. However, even after

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/class'
```

I still get the same error message.

Which module I should include in order to access this method? I am using Rails 4, with `protected_attributes` gem.

Update1: add `include ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity`

Comment: I found here how to include class_attribute from a module: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4406248 (basically it goes inside the "included" block. I don't think it directly answers this question, but will help other people who searched for the general question of including class_attribute in a module.